# Android if the button can be clicked to change the text on the button that

Tags: android, button, loops

I find it difficult to make a loop on the button onclick conditions.
I want the button can be clicked repeatedly on the button and the text was changed at random.

what should I add?

```
private String[] myString; 
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
    Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 

    final String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];


    Button btn2;
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            ((Button) v).setText(q);



        }

    });
```

}
}

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, can you provide example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your String `q` is initialized in the `onCreate` which is called only at startup.

You need to move this in your `onClick` method

Answer (score 1):

//njzk2 answer is right try this

```
    Button btn2;
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

   String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            ((Button) v).setText(q);



        }

    });
```

Comment: `((Button) v).setText(myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);` makes just as much sense. Why create the `String q` in the first place?

Comment: if I did this the OP will get confused. my answer just moved the deceleration. so that he will know. I dont wan to confuse the OP.

Comment: ya @Jave you are right. I have edit permission for others answers also.

Comment: the above code works only once onclick, if I click the button text does not change it again.

Comment: @adig 'rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)' what this will do? 'myString.length' always same right.